# Search of Element inside a multi-dimensional List Not Working. Any Clue

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to search for an element inside a multi-dimensional list, but its not working. Anything wrong in my search ?? Below is the simple code and I tried searching using 'in' and 'any' but didnt work..

```
list1 = []
list1.append([['hello'], ['blue'], ['bla']])

print list1

list1.append([['hello'], ['blue'], ['bla']])
print list1

#if 'hello' in list1:
if any('hello' in x for x in list1):
    print "Found Hello"
else:
    print "Not Found Hello"
```

Any guess whats the error I am doing ?? Kindly share in your inputs/comments.

Thanks In Adv !
Vimo

Comment: My intention is : a. Say I am reading variables from a list, and if that element is any new color I will put it in a different list along with two other elements. Eg: [[[red], [car], [flight]]] b. Say if the next color is new, then I wanted to add is in a new sub list like: Eg: [[[red], [car], [flight]] , [[green], [cycle], [truck]]] c. Say if the next color is the same color, I wanted to append to the same sub-list like, instead of creating a new sub-list Eg: [[[red], [car], [flight], [Jeans]] , [[green], [cycle], [truck]]] So only I wanted to iterate all sub-list.

Comment: And also the sub-list can keep increasing depending on the new colors.. So each and everytime I wanted to check if the color is already existing in the multi-dimensional list or not before adding new details into the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `list1` should be a list of lists, then the problem is that you are appending a list to `list1`, in this case, use `extend` instead.

If you want to search a item in a nested list (any number of levels), you can use this function

```
def in_nested_list(item, x):
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        return x == item
    else:
        return any(in_nested_list(item, ix) for ix in x)

list1 = []
list1.append([['hello'], ['blue'], ['bla']])

print list1

list1.append([['hello'], ['blue'], ['bla']])
print list1

#if 'hello' in list1:
if in_nested_list('hello', list1):
    print "Found Hello"
else:
    print "Not Found Hello"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Malbarbo ! I tried using the function example which you posted, its giving the below error !

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types

Any clue or suggestions why its giving that error ? I just called the function as,
in_nested_list(x, 'hello')

Comment: Understood the issue that, its because my list also has the same keyword "list"... But still its not working.. What should be the input to the function ??

Comment: To make the usage clean I change the parameters name and add complete the example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example.. Appreciate your timely help !!

Comment: Your are welcome. Please, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Hello Malbarbo.. Just a quick query, can I tweak the function to also say in which particular sub-list the element exists ? so that based on that info I can extend or append further data's onto the particular sub-list.  Do I need to add any local variable inside the function to store the sub-list info apart from function returning either TRUE or FALSE ?

Comment: Reading your question comment, maybe you need another approach. See an idea here http://pastebin.com/P2L6Thz8 . May you should open a new question and formulate what exactly (with expected result) you want to do.

Comment: Hello Malbarbo.. I have captured the idea of the function in the below link,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923346/searching-for-an-element-inside-a-multi-dimensional-list-and-to-return-the-sub-l

If you have any suggestions, kindly provide your feedback !

Answer (score 0):

You need to go one layer deeper, like:

```
for l in list1:
    for item in l:
        if 'hello' in item:
            #do something
```

Or use `list.extend()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find 'hello' you'll have to search down one further level:

```
if any('hello' in x for middle_list in list1 for x in middle_list):
    print "Found Hello"
```