# Searching for an element inside a multi-dimensional list and to return the sub-list number?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Previously I had a question on finding whether an element exists in a nested list or not and got the response in the below link.

[Search of Element inside a multi-dimensional List Not Working. Any Clue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902602/search-of-element-inside-a-multi-dimensional-list-not-working-any-clue)

Was wondering if the function could as well send out a value which says in which sub-list does the element exists ? Below is the code which says if the element exits or not:

```
def in_nested_list(item, x):
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        return x == item
    else:
        return any(in_nested_list(item, ix) for ix in x)

list1 = []
list1.append([['red'], ['blue'], ['bla']])

print list1

list1.append([['hello'], ['blue'], ['bla']])
print list1

if in_nested_list('hello', list1):
    print "Found Hello"
else:
    print "Not Found Hello"
```

Was wondering how could I change that function to also say in which sub-list does the element exits so that I can append further data based onto particular sub list.

a. From the above example, the if condition will print that Hello is found. But if it also returns or saves an output variable like which sublist_no i.e. sub-list 1 in the above case, so that I can append further variable.

Eg: Now the output return TRUE and also the sub-list number as 1, so that I can do the following process after calling the function.

```
list1[sublist_no].append(['Bug'])
```

Say if I search for the element red, the output will be TRUE with sublist_no as 0, so that I can append some more variable to the 1st list.
`list1[sublist_no].append('[Rasberry]')  # i.e. onto the first sub-list.`

Any clue on the above query ? Kindly drop in your comment...

Answer (score 0):

Since your original function can deal with much more complicated nested structures than just lists of lists, so should your nested '`index`' function:

```
def in_nested_list(item, x):
    if item == x:
        return []
    if isinstance(x, list):
        for i, ix in enumerate(x):
            r = in_nested_list(item, ix)
            if r != -1:
                return [i] + r  # highest level index plus path in sublist
    return -1  # not found in any (nested) sublist

# if not found at all: return -1
# if item == x: return []
# else: return [a, b, c] such that item == x[a][b][c]

> in_nested_list(3, [[1, 2], [3, 4]])
[1, 0]

> in_nested_list(3, [[1, 2], [[5, 3], 4]])
[1, 0, 1]

> in_nested_list(3, 3)
[]

> in_nested_list(3, [1, 2])
# -1
```

This allows you to append stuff at any nesting level of your choosing. As for your question, the index of the sublist in your simple structure would be `in_nested_list(...)[0]` (if present, raises Error otherwise).

Comment: Thanks for your response Schwobaseggl.. I tried running the example but somehow its going into loop error:
  File "./listeg_sch.py", line 8, in in_nested_list
    x = in_nested_list(item, ix)
  File "./listeg_sch.py", line 4, in in_nested_list
    if item == x:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
Went clueless..

Comment: I edited my answer a little. But I see. Strings are iterable themselves, I only tested it with ints. Some tweaks will do. Gimme a minute ;)

Answer (score 0):

I took leverage to modify your function.

```
def in_nested(item, container):
    if not isinstance(container, list):
        raise TypeError
    for elem in container:
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            found = in_nested(item, elem)
            if not found:
                pass
            elif isinstance(found, bool):
                # Item is present in this list
                return elem
                # List containing item is present in this container
                # Comment above return to use it.
                return container
            else:
                # Return the deepest list and not the most outer list containing it.
                return found
        else:
            return item == elem


_input = [[['red'], ['blue'], ['bla']], [['hello'], ['blue'], ['bla']]]
out = in_nested('hello', _input)
if out:
    print "Found Hello", out
else:
    print "Not Found Hello"

out.append('new')
print 'Added new to original input', _input

out = in_nested('Hello', _input)  # hello with capital H
if out:
    print "Found Hello", out
else:
    print "Not Found Hello"

# Prints:
# Found Hello ['hello']
# Added new to original input [[['red'], ['blue'], ['bla']], [['hello', 'new'], ['blue'], ['bla']]]
# Not Found Hello
```

Note: It gives you the target list itself, if item is present else None. You don't have to locate the list again. Just append to the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Anshu.. So this is basically returning the inner most list itself.. So can I also get just the inner list number ? something like that ? for example : in the above scenario the inner list number is 1, since 'hello' is present in the 2nd inner list ?

Comment: As per your requirement, I don't see why you need the list number. But if you need it, approach like @schwobaseggl answer would make more sense.

Comment: Hello Anshu.. True.. when ran the case you gave, its basically adding into the inner list itself like:
[[['red'], ['blue'], ['bla']], [['hello', 'new'], ['blue'], ['bla']]]

instead of adding the element new to the end of the 2nd inner list.. 
[[['red'], ['blue'], ['bla']], [['hello'], ['blue'], ['bla'],['new']]]

Because in which ever inner list I find the element present, I wanted to add few more elements to the end of the list and not within the list itself..so only I was looking for inner list number, so I though can add something like,
_input[1].append(['new']) and also few more variables

Comment: In such a case you can ```return container``` instead of ```return elem```. Have edited the answer to incorporate that.